# Fuse ESB Graphical tool for data transformation

Tags: transformation, fuseesb

Is there a graphical tools that is included in Fuse ESB or available outside that I can use for creating data transformation between source and target data elements?

Comment: There is Fuse IDE that you can use to define the routes. That could also give transformation capabilities. I dont think you can get a full fledged ETL type mapping capabilities.

Answer (score 0):

There is currently no such tool out of the box with JBoss Fuse. It is on the roadmap for a future release (likely 6.2) and we have some work in progress code which needs to be finished first.

It allows you to use the web console (based on hawtio - http://hawt.io/) to do the data transformation mapping. And leveraging the Dozer library for the actual mapping implementation.